# Change Network Bandwidth

Tags: networking

I am using `ethtool` to change the bandwidth to 10MB/s. Since this is my first time using this program, I am struggling with the correct syntax to change it. I have tried something like:

`ethtool -s --change speed 10 eth0`

I know this is incorrect since the command line shot back an error. Can anyone suggest what the correct syntax is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ethtool) command should be:

```
ethtool -s devname speed X duplex half|full
```

I think `--change` is long option and `-s` is a short option.

> ethtool -s devname [speed N] [duplex half|full] [port tp|aui|bnc|mii] [mdix auto|on|off] [autoneg on|off] [advertise N] [phyad N] [xcvr internal|external] [wol p|u|m|b|a|g|s|d...]  [sopass xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc] [msglvl N |
>                 msglvl type on|off ...]

So you can try for example:

```
ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex half
```

or:

```
ethtool --change eth0 speed 10 duplex half
```